# Connect to google cloud ubuntu server with ssh tunnel forwarder on python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

I am using a Google Cloud instance running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to connect to the server with ssh using the python 3 sshtunnel library.  This is the code I am using:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
  'host_ip',
  ssh_username='name',
  ssh_password='password',
  remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)
server.start()
```

However, I get the following error:

> BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         5     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
>         6 )
>   ----> 7 server.start()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py in start(self)
>      1222         if not self.is_active:
>      1223             self._raise(BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError,
>   -> 1224                         reason='Could not establish session to SSH gateway')
>      1225         for _srv in self._server_list:
>      1226             thread = threading.Thread(
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py in _raise(self, exception, reason)
>      1034     def _raise(self, exception=BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError, reason=None):
>      1035         if self._raise_fwd_exc:
>   -> 1036             raise exception(reason)
>      1037         else:
>      1038             self.logger.error(repr(exception(reason)))
>
> BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

I am using same code for Digital Ocean droplets and I have no problem there. I use an SSH connection to connect to mysql.  I can connect to the Google Cloud server using putty and filezilla with SSH but I cant connect on python. How can I solve this ?

The ports that are open on the instance:
[image: my open port image]

Comment: Hello @erkan, have you tried to use port 22 rather than 3306 with remote_bind_address, or open port 3306 from the GCP [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) ? I found this [guide](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage-scenarios) to be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Fady, I use port 22 to connect filezilla and putty. I try using port 22 but it is not work on python. I add my port image on question  you can see.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @erkan, I have never used Python, but from the message “could not establish session to SSH gateway”, it seems that it is a connection issue. Could it be that you have not added the private key file? Also I am not sure if you need a password as Linux GCE instances are usually password-less for security reasons. On the other hand, if your objective is to connect to a mysql db you may check this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) that could be useful for your use case. I hope this helps.